# How to get type=time field in DJango

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to use input `type = time` in Django. But every time my `type = text`. I have tried it:

```
field_name = forms.TimeField()
<!--return-->
<input type="text" name="field_name" required id="id_field_name">
```

this:

```
time_st = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M'))
<!--return-->
<input type="text" name="time_st" value="" required id="id_time_st">
```

How to get an effect like this:

```
<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt" class="form-control" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Appologies if this is not the answer you are looking for I was trying to decrypt your question.

So you have a form which is something like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
   time = forms.TimeField()
```

This is your basic django form which has a field called time.

In your django view you will need something like the following which will parse the form making it "usable".

```
def form_handler(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.valid_data['time'])
            return redirect('valid_time_url_redirect')
        return ... # failure of validation see form.errors
    form = MyForm()
    return render('django_template.html', {'form': form})
```

This is probably not valid code but hopefully it will point you in the right direction as to what you need to do.

- There is [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#timefield) and [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield) in both the models and the form classes. Make sure you are using the correct one for your usecase. Also make sure you take a look at the expected inputs for each field. Look at [time_input_formats](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_INPUT_FORMATS), this is a common gotcha for using these fields.